# Supplement code for the "Algorithms in Java, part 5" book (Sedgewick)

Tags: java, algorithm

We are having an "Advanced Algorithms" curriculum at my college and each of us got an assignment to describe a specific algorithm from the "Algorithms in Java" book. We also have to implement the code from the book (in Java of course) to show how the algorithm works on a concrete example.

The classes which we have to use for graphs, nodes, edges etc. are already available in the book, but it seems to me (and to some other students) that the code has a few errors that prevent it to compile.

The only implementation I managed to find was this:
http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/Algs3.java5/code.txt
But that is the same code from the book, and it doesn't work.

The code I'm having problem with is here:

```
  GraphSPT(Graph G, int s)  
  { int V = G.V(), N = 0;
    wt = new double[V]; spt = new Edge[V]; 
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) wt[v] = maxWT; 
    intQueue Q = new intQueue(G.E());
    wt[s] = 0.0; Q.put(s);  Q.put(V);
    while (!Q.empty()) 
    { int v;
      while ((v = Q.get()) == V) 
        { if (N++ > V) return; Q.put(V); }
      AdjList A = G.getAdjList(v);
      for (Edge e = A.beg(); !A.end(); e = A.nxt()) /* this line is the one with the problem */
        { int w = e.other(v); 
          double P = wt[v] + e.wt();
          if (P < wt[w]) 
            { wt[w] = P; Q.put(w); spt[w] = e; }
        }
    }
  }
```

I marked the problematic line. AdjList in the line before is an interface, but the getAdjList() method returns an instance of the AdjLinkedList class, which contains implementations of the beg(), end() and nxt() methods. The problem occurs because they return integers, and not instances of the Edge class. If I change the initializer in the for loop to "int e...", then the code inside the loop doesn't work because it calls the other() and wt() methods on the "e" object.

Did someone have the same problem maybe, or does anyone know if there are any working code implementations from the book available for download?

P.S. Using classes from the book is allowed, I just have to represent graphs with my own code which would not be a problem at all if the classes actually worked :)

Comment: What is the 'problem'? Do you get an error message?

Comment: @birryree Yes, "Edge e" in the loop initialization expects Edge objects from A.beg(), and not "int". I can post the output tomorrow  (I'm not on my machine right now).

Comment: Would replacing that line with `for(Edge e : A)` work?

Comment: @Kevin `public int beg() { t = adj[v]; return t == null ? -1 : t.v; }` The method returns an int. 

@DanielFischer I'll let you know tomorrow. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Well then that's your problem, `beg` returns an `int` but you're trying to store it in an `Edge`.  Try Daniel Fischer's suggestion; you may need to implement, I believe it's `Iterable`.

Comment: I know that, it's the error from the book which I described in the question. Will try with Daniels advice, thank you both.

Comment: In my opinion, authors that create that kind of "Java" as code samples should be shot. If any person types that kind of code in the company I work, they will get a serious talking to. As long as you everybody is aware that's not the way things should be programmed.

Comment: @DanielFischer Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried `extends Iterable` on the `AdjList interface` and `implements Iterable` on the `AdjLinkedList`. The error I get is `Can only iterate over the array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable`

Comment: It is the Bellman-Ford algorithm example from the book.

Answer (score 0):

If A.end() is returning a boolean (or an integer 0/1) that represents if it is at the end of the list or not then A.beg() might be returning a boolean (or an integer 0/1) specifying if it is at the beginning of the list or not. So perhaps whoever was writing the the example code was not the same person who wrote the Edge code and was expecting different functionality from the beg() function.

Comment: Who knows... In the end, our professor accepted the theoretical explanation of the algorithm and let us pass. 

Thank you everyone for your help, anyway!